# Query the SML/NJ REPL for signatures or structures?

Tags: sml, smlnj

Is there a way to get a list of the `signature`s or `structure`s available in the top-level environment from the SML/NJ REPL?  I'm looking to get a listing of the signatures/structures that appear to be defined in the `sources.cm` files in the sml source directory.  Something along the lines of

```
- signature s = LIST;
```

only listing the bindings in the top-level environment instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the [internal structures](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/Compiler/pages/compiler.html) that SML/NJ provides:

```
fun boundSignatures () =
  let
    fun isSignature symbol = Symbol.nameSpace symbol = Symbol.SIGspace
    val signatures = List.filter isSignature (EnvRef.listBoundSymbols ())
  in
    List.app (fn s => print (Symbol.name s ^ "\n")) signatures
  end
```

Please note that, due to autoloading, `EnvRef.listBoundSymbols` won't return symbol names for modules which are available, but haven't yet been loaded:

```
- boundSignatures ();
ENVREF
val it = () : unit
- signature S = STATICENV;
[autoloading]
[autoloading done]
- boundSignatures ();
STATICENV
ENVREF
S
val it = () : unit
```

Comment: works great, thanks.  To force the autoloading, I found I can call `CM.make("$/basis.cm")` to force the basis values to be added.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi thanks, I didn't know that. BTW, the parentheses are redundant in that call: `CM.make "$/basis.cm"`. In SML you only need parentheses when you need to explicitly specify associativity. they're not used as a syntax for function calls. A space is used to designate function calls.